# change a struct type to map type pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, dtype

Im trying to change the `Struct` type to `Map` type. I found this this solution -->

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,lit,create_map
df = df.withColumn("propertiesMap",create_map(
        lit("salary"),col("properties.salary"),
        lit("location"),col("properties.location")
        )).drop("properties")
```

but in my case I need to wrtie alot of `lit` which I tried to avoid with for loop but seems like it does not work as when I try to print schema, i get this error `'list' object has no attribute 'printSchema'`

my code is here:

```
field_names = [field.name for field in next(field for field in df4.schema.fields if field.name=="values").dataType.fields]

df5= [df4.withColumn("valuesMap", 
                     create_map(lit(field_name),
                                col(f"values.{field_name}"))) for field_name in field_names]
```

Comment: you can create multiple columns using a list *within a select*. your current approach creates multiple dataframes - each having 1 extra column created from the loop, not all in one df.

Comment: @samkart comment needs to be given due attention. My advice give us a sample df and expected output